# Is there any way to get numbers separated by comma?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have

```
line = "abcde:abc/abcd=(12, 20)"
```

and I want to get `12` and `20` in an array. My solution is:

```
array_line = line[/\(.*?\)/].delete('()').delete(' ').split(",")
```

Is there any better way to solve it using ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This if you want an array of strings

```
line.scan(/\d+/) #=> ["12", "20"]
```

or an array of numbers

```
line.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) #=> [12, 20]
```

As per comments another example and method:

```
line = "abcde:123, type/onetwothree = (12, 20)"
line[/(?<=\()[0-9,\s]+(?=\))/].split(', ') #=> ["12", "20"]
```

Here we use a lookahead and a lookbehind to match only the numbers in between the brackets.

Comment: AWESOME! What if there is a comma and number ahead of the brackets? Like line = "abcde:123, type/onetwothree = (12, 20)"

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
require 'json'
JSON.parse "[#{'abcde:abc/abcd=(12, 20)'[/(?<=\().*?(?=\))/]}]"
#⇒ [12, 20]
```

Comment: That is truly an original solution. Most people don't know about `String#[]` having regexp support.

Answer (score 0):

This one could be a good answer as well:

```
line[/\((.*?)\)/, 1].delete(' ').split(",")
```

Comment: Add `.map(&:to_i)` for integer values, too.